# sorting differences

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am currently learning a number of different sorting algorithm. being curious with the differences,I tried to find the information of them but none is good enough. so here is my questions, in term of performance and their concept, what is the differences among bubble sort, selection sort, insertion sort, shell sort and quick sort.

Comment: Really? *None* of the information you found on the web was good enough? I'm flabbergasted. And I'm also pretty certain that, if the 4 googolplex bytes of information on the web regarding sorting wasn't good enough, we won't be able to help either :-)

Comment: Not directly an answer, but you might enjoy three beautiful quicksorts:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMnn0Jq0J-E&feature=PlayList&p=AFFC9CBB57988795&index=8

Comment: Also sounds like this should be tagged 'homework'

Comment: Pax's comment is spot on. There is a wealth of info. out there. Try googling "sort algorithm wiki" to start with...

Comment: Sounds like Data Structures homework.

Comment: How are you learning the algorithms? What reference material are you using that hasn't discussed the differences already? (No, really. Tell us. That way others can know what resources to avoid.)

Comment: "The Art of Computer Programming" -- Donald Knuth

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia gives good [brief descriptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Summaries_of_popular_sorting_algorithms) of the popular sorting algorithms, as well as [comparisons of their speeds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms).

Comment: Thanks for the link! That's a great reference to have in my back pocket.

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia doesn't mention the incredible [timsort](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt), which is what Python uses (a clever variant of Natural Mergesort). When one of my Pythonista colleagues presented it in a tech talk, my other colleague Josh Bloch, a Java guru, was so enthused he started coding it for Java then and there on his laptop -- apparently it will likely become the standard Java sort in some near-future version of the JVM;-)

Comment: +1 Learned something new today, and I am already a python enthusiast

Comment: @Tom, great to hear I've been helpful -- thanks for letting me know!

Comment: A smart person can give ok answer to smart question, a wise person can give good answer to good question, a sage can give brilliant answer to dumb question.

Answer (score 2):

http://vision.bc.edu/~dmartin/teaching/sorting/anim-html/all.html is by far the best visual explanation of the sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a nice table which compares a lot of sorting algorithms.
Take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

I like this [animated sorting algorithm page](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/) that describes the differences between several sorts with several different inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) and check the main article pages for each of the sorting methods you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: QuickSort best, BubbleSort worst.  Except of course when dealing with the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my summary of sorting algorithms:
Concept :

1) In bubble sort, at every iteration you pick highest number from the array and place it at the last position, you do exactly opposite in case of selection of sort ,you select smallest number at every iteration and put it at the first location of array O(n^2).

2) In insertion sort you divide array in two partitions ,one sorted partition and other unsorted partition, and at every iteration we take an element from unsorted portion and insert it into sorted portion. O(n^2). { In place sorting ,stable algorithm }

3) Quick sort ,as the name suggests is the fast sorting algorithm ,At every iteration we finalize the position of pivot element.In short we rank the pivots at every iteration. Average case time O(n lg n) worst case O(n^2) { Worst case is rare. Good alternative to Merge sort as Quicks sort is in place algoithm and value of constant is much smaller compaired to merge sort.. But it is not stable.}

you can see comparision of sorting algorithms here http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/sortcomp.html